# Github Action running container with options

Tags: docker, github, containers, github-actions

In docs there is described how to run container with additional options: [Workflow syntax for GitHub Actions - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontaineroptions)

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: Container with name
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: 
      image: ghcr.io/repo/image:latest
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      options: --name myContainerName
```

But snippet above create and start docker without name argument... and of course other argument doesn't work, like `--workdir`.

Name of container is generated like this: 31ec555a1aav41a5bffe95da6f8b775b_ghcriorepoimage10_c998dc

**Updated:**
It's funny, because when i read logs, there are twice `--name` argument:

```
/usr/bin/docker create --name 31ec555a1aav41a5bffe95da6f8b775b_ghcriorepoimage10_c998dc --label f88420 --network github_network_a6029d55c6024481ba937e113e978280 --name myContainerName...
```

Comment: Can you verify from the logs what arguments the container actually gets? Seems like in this case there would be two `--name` arguments present, where the latter is the one you provide, and that should end up being a valid name for the container name.

Comment: Updated: Added log result.

Comment: So is the custom name you provide not a valid name for the container then? How are you verifying this?

Comment: @LeadingMoominExpert: Good question! If Github works inside on my docker, everything should be great. But the same situation is with flag `--workdir`. Validaded by `pwd`, always return path like `/_w/reponame/reponame`.

Comment: @LeadingMoominExpert: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/878